# questão de múltiplas escolhas em APS MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto aonde ele vai ter questão de múltiplas escolhas.
Meu problema é que não estou conseguindo mostrar apenas as questões que quero, por exemplo ao clicar nas questões iria aparecer para o usuário a pegunta numero 1 com as questões ,depois que ele termina, avança para questão numero 2 assim por diante. 
Meu problema é que estou conseguindo mostrar todas as informações no lugar de ser só uma em especifico(estou usando o to list para mostrar porém não achei uma alternativa para mostrar apenas uma informação).

Codigo da View

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Questão)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Questão)
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Agora o codigo do Controle

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Fornecedor.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: **`Fornecedor`**?

Comment: Nome do banco aonde estão as questões (esqueci de mudar ) mas seria questões

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Para devolver apenas uma informação, use:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Questoes.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Que ira te retornar apenas um registro

**Ou use o Where para devolver algo especifico**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Questoes.Where(x => x.Questao == 1));
}
```